# djstripe admin cannot view synced plans or products

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have a problem when I use django admin to view products and prices in djstripe. I have synced everything on Stripe portal. I get an error `Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/djstripe/plan/ Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

How do I solve this? Been stuck here

[error in django admin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXqRT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: looks like you have something broken somewhere... the complete error trace will be nice.

Comment: Could you provide more information regarding your integration? It looks like a python error. What treatment are you doing before/while loading the djstripe product page? Are you seeing any particular errors in your Stripe dashboard logs https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs ?

Comment: Stripe dashboard logs seem all good 200 response code. I pretty much followed https://ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/django-stripe-monthly-subscription tutorial just got stuck at loading product page